# Pointer + operator issue

Tags: c++, pointers

I recently started learning C++ and I'm a bit confused with pointers. Could you please explain me WHY in the following example variable "a"  equals 1 and z = 0??????  I'm really confused!!!!!!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
 int a;
 int Z[3] ={1, 2, 3}; 
 int *z;
 z=Z;
 a = (*z)--;
 cout<<a<<" "<<*z<<"\n";
 system ("pause");
}
```

logically ,I believe, first of all *z points to the 0-th element of the array - that is 1
then -- operator decreases 0-th element's value by 1 and now z[0] should be 0
but WHY it still returns 1 for "a" variable????

Comment: Always use int main()

Comment: post-decrement returns the current value of a variable, *then* decrements it. This has nothing to do with pointers.

Answer (score 3):

The order of your operations is this:

```
a = *z //*z = 1 here
*z = *z - 1 //*z = 0 here
```

Decrement operator happens after the assignment.

Comment: `z` is a pointer, this should say `*z` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the decrement operator is after the expression.

```
a = (*z)--;
```

Here first *z is evaluated and a is assigned the value (1). After that *z is decremented to zero.

If it had been

```
a = --(*z);
```

Then *z would have evaluated and decremented 1st. After that the value would have been assigned to a. Hence in this case both would be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Post-decrement, `thing--`, yields the value *before* decrementing; so `a` is assigned the previous value of `*z`, which is 1.

Pre-decrement, `--thing`, yields the value *after* decrementing, so changing to `a = --(*z);` would set `a` to zero.